# Can't change TextView when in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, xml, layout, textview

I have a Text View that I need to place into another Relative Layout, in my activity.
When I do this though, the text that is assigned to it (pokeDesc) is changed to (pokeWeight) for some reason.

Layout file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivPokeView"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvPName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ivPokeView"
    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivPokeView"
    android:text="@string/pName"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvPEntry"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvPName"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvPName"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:text="@string/pEntry" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivType1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ivPokeView"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ivType2"
    android:src="@drawable/fire" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivType2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/ivPokeView"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ivType1"
    android:layout_marginRight="23dp"
    android:src="@drawable/grass" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvHeight"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvPEntry"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvPEntry"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:text="Height" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvWeight"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tvHeight"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tvHeight"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvPName"
    android:text="Weight" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ivType1"
    android:layout_margin="20dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rect_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDesc"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:text="@string/pDesc"
        android:textSize="17dp" />
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

code from assigning text view variables

```
 //Initalises all UI items in the activity
public void initVars(){
    pName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPName);
    pEntry = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPEntry);
    pDesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDesc);
    pHeight = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHeight);
    pWeight = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvWeight);
    pPic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivPokeView);
    tPic1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivType1);
    tPic2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivType2);
}
```

code to get data from JSON file

```
        //Sets the pokemons name
pokeName = pindex.getString("Name");
pName.setText(pokeName);
//Sets the pokemons entry
pokeEntry = pindex.getString("Entry");
pEntry.setText(pokeEntry);
//Sets pokemon description
pokeDesc = pindex.getString("desc");
pDesc.setText(pokeDesc);
//Sets height
pokeHeight = pindex.getString("height");
pHeight.setText("Height: "+pokeHeight);
//Sets weight
pokeWeight = pindex.getString("weight");
pWeight.setText("Weigth: "+pokeWeight);
```

[image: poke_layout on my phone]

Comment: You have so many textview's. Which one are you talking about ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there are so many textview's, and you need your weight textview below #001 textview.

You are lucky that i know about pokemon

`tvPEntry` -> i guess this is the text on which you are setting text "**#001**"

Please check below. I have added the textview `tvWeight` below `tvPEntry`

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivPokeView"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvPName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ivPokeView"
    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivPokeView"
    android:text="@string/pName"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvPEntry"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvPName"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvPName"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:text="@string/pEntry" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvWeight"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvPEntry"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvPName"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:text="Weight" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivType1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ivPokeView"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ivType2"
    android:src="@drawable/fire" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivType2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/ivPokeView"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ivType1"
    android:layout_marginRight="23dp"
    android:src="@drawable/grass" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvHeight"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvPEntry"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvPEntry"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:text="Height" />


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ivType1"
    android:layout_margin="20dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rect_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDesc"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:text="@string/pDesc"
        android:textSize="17dp" />
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: So what you are saying is that by changing its relative position in the code it will allocated in a different area in the program? I thought that was determined through the alignment references (e.g. layout_alignTop="@id/ivType2")

Comment: With all these textview's it is already confusing. I have changed the position of weight textview below the entry textview. Only alignment will not solve. You need to use layout_below attribute too